# Growth rate of ordered bounded partitions

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Let $P_n(k,i)=|\{(d_1,\cdots,d_i): \ \sum_{j=1}^id_j=n, \ \forall j\ 1\leq d_j\leq k\}|$, the number of ordered partitions of $n$ into $i$ parts with individual parts bounded by $k$, with no piece having length 0. To be extra clear, if $n=9, \ k=4, \ i=3$ then $1+4+4=9$ and $4+1+4=9$ denote two different partitions.

I'm looking for *elementary* semi-decent upper bounds on $P_n(k,i)$ as $n$ gets large. We can assume $n\gg k$ and $[n/k]\leq i\leq n$.

For example $P_n(k,i)\leq k^{i-1}$, is the dumbest bound possible, combinatorially speaking. Another bound is $\binom{n}{i}$ by picking $i$ partitions. The second bound is somewhat worse but captures that $P_n(k,i)$ starts to get larger for $i>[n/k]$ but then ultimately goes down. Specifically we have $P_n(k,[t/k])=P(k,n)=1$.

Can one do significantly better than this without resorting to difficult estimates involving Gaussian polynomials, generating functions, etc.?

Comment: Another word for ordered partition (as used here) is [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)).

Answer (score 1):

Generating functions are a powerful tool, you should have no fear in using them.

Here we have that 
$$P_n(k,i)=[z^n]\;(z+z^2+\ldots+z^k)^i = [z^n]\;z^i\left(\frac{1-z^k}{1-z}\right)^i = [z^{n-i}]\;\left(\frac{1-z^k}{1-z}\right)^i,$$
and:
$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^i}=\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\binom{i+m-1}{m}z^m,\tag{1}$$
$$(1-z^k)^i = \sum_{r=0}^{i}\binom{i}{r}(-1)^r z^{kr},\tag{2}$$
so multiplying $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get:
$$P_n(k,i)=\sum_{\substack{m+kr=n-i\\r\leq i}}\binom{i+m-1}{m}\binom{i}{r}(-1)^r\tag{3}.$$
Now the main contribute to this last sum is given by the first term $(r=0)$. The other ones are much smaller and, additionally, there is cancellation due to the alternating sign. So we have:

> $$\binom{n-1}{n-i}-i\binom{n-k-1}{n-k-i}\leq P_n(k,i)\leq\binom{n-1}{n-i}.\tag{4}$$

Comment: I'm not sure I believe that the other terms are much smaller than the first term.

Comment: Yes they are, $\binom{i+m-1}{m}=\binom{i+m-1}{i-1}$ can be regarded as a polynomial of (fixed) degree $i-1$ in the variable $i+m-1$. So going from $r$ to $r+1$ the binomial coefficient $\binom{i}{r}$ increases a bit, but the binomial coefficient $\binom{i+m-1}{m}$ decreases a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I like this idea, in that it seems like one can actually try to get a bound involving $(i,k,n)$ by looking at the first few terms of the sum. On the other hand, the upper bound is combinatorially trivial. It looks like if $k$ is sufficiently small, then you should be able to do much better than the upper bound.